# Ajax Load Image untill page is fully loaded

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is what I am using to load links that I click (menu_Nav) into a `<div>` (`apDiv2`).

```
$('.menu_nav').click(function() {
var href = $(this).attr('href');
$('#apDiv2').hide().load(href).fadeIn('normal');
return false;
});
```

Some of the pages take a while to load which I understand is normal. I would like to place a loading `.gif` image in the center of the div/page container until the content is fully loaded. To check out the page in action please visit http://www.ForeverThaEmpire.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send a ajax request to get the content of your "href" url, with a completion callback;

While the ajax request is being performed, you have a change to set the content of your #apDiv2 to the loading.gif image, and it will be cleared out when ajax request completes.

```
$('.menu_nav').click(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    // I Assume that /loading.gif is the url to your gif file
    $('#apDiv2').empty().append($('<img src="/loading.gif" />'));

    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: href,
        success: function(content)
        {
            $('#apDiv2').html (content);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: can I use an array in the ajax line to get the content in the apDiv2.... becuase some pages are html some pages are php?